# Можно ли получить доступ к куке чужого сайта?

Tags: javascript, cookie, безопасность

Есть скрипт. Он подключается на другой сайт. Но мне для передачи данных с сервера нужно поставить кук ибо иначе я не знаю как сделать, что я успешно делаю в фильтре, который настроен на файл (фильтр вызывается когда идёт обращение на файл). Но штука в том что у этого кука домен равен ip-шнику моего сервака (то бишь откуда тянется скрипт). И получить кук в `js` (библиотека `js.cookies`) я не могу. Пробовал в фильтре задавать домен того сайта где стоит скрипт, но кук при этом вообще не ставится.  как быть? подскажете?

все прочие `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` у меня есть.

Comment: Не поясняйте на пальцах, лучше покажите всем код, а то так трудно понять что у вас там не так и что подсказать...

Comment: @Алексей а код тут при чём? у меня проблема с тем как кук ставится, что домен не тот. А получить куки можно и по команде в консоле `document.cookies`. Но кука который я поставил со своего сервера нет. В хроме я его вижу.

Comment: Нельзя поставить/получить доступ к кукам другого домена, только текущий домен (или его родитель).

Comment: А, вам нужно получить доступ к куке другого домена? Неее, это запрещает Same-Origin Policy

Comment: @Алексей как тогда быть? может как-то ещё передать данные

Comment: @Visman как тогда быть? может как-то ещё передать данные

Comment: Всё таки я бы на вашем месте конкретизировал/уточнил саму формулировку вопроса и ваши условия, как-то так: два сайта один мой, другой нет, или два сайта, но на моём сервере ... что значит скрипт "подключается на другой сайт" в смысле запрашивает куки другого сайта или физически у вас есть доступ к коду другого сайта .. и т.п. Вопрос должен быть понятен не только вам одному. А если мы всё таки правильно вас поняли и вам нужно любыми путями получить доступ к куке чужого сайта, то вам уже все ответили - что это невозможно как не крути.

Comment: Прочтите:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Правило_ограничения_домена  и
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy  и
https://www.w3.org/Security/wiki/Same_Origin_Policy  и
https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy

Comment: @Алексей один сайт мой. другой не мой, других людей. Они подключают к себе скрипт в `head`. На моём сайте есть фильтр на этот файл. В этом фильтре я ставлю куки на сайт где стоит скрипт с данными для этого скрипта.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62659/discussion-between--and-tsyklop).